# Joomla - Page Builder - With Publish Workflow

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

We have recently built a site on Joomla and have used the SP Page Builder. But unfortunately, the SP Page Builder does not have the Workflow / User Access mechanism where one set of users create the content / page and other set of users preview it and publish. Are there any other alternative Page Builder plugins that provide this functionality?

Many Thanks

Comment: Please always post ALL Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  I wish there was a tag prompt so that I didn't have to type this on every Joomla question.

Comment: Thanks for that, will post it on that Forum.